# Migrate base image on self hosted agent

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devops

When visiting my build agent on Azure, I get a warning that I must migrate away from Windows Server 2016 base image. I have updated the base image to the recommended version using the link provided in the warning message: [How do I migrate my Windows Server 2016 container groups to Windows Server 2019 images?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-faq#how-do-i-migrate-my-windows-server-2016-container-groups-to-windows-server-2019-images-)

The warning is still appearing in Azure Portal even though I have updated the version of the image. How can I verify that my build agent is running on Windows Server 2019 base image? This is a self-hosted agent so I'm not able to see it in DevOps -> AgentPool -> Azure Pipeline "Agent specifications"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose that you could run a command line task with "systeminfo" to echo the agent information.

By the way, you could also run this command with your local CMD directly.

[image]
[image]